# Filling landscape PDF with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I try to fill a PDF form with PDFBox and I managed to do it well with a portrait oriented document. But I have a problem when filling a document in landscape mode. The fields are filled up, but the text orientation is not good. It appear vertically like if it was still in portrait but in a rotation of 90 degrees.

Here is my simplified code:

```
PDDocument pdfDoc = PDDocument.load(MY_FILE);
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();

acroForm.getField("aAddressLine1").setValue("ADDRESS1_HERE");
acroForm.getField("aAddressLine2").setValue("ADDRESS1_HERE");
acroForm.getField("country").setValue("COUNTRY_HERE");

pdfDoc.save(PATH_HERE);
pdfDoc.close();
```

Did you manage to fill a PDF document in landscape mode?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A look into PDAppearance.java (the class responsible for creating the appearance), PDFBox does not seem to take all rotation relevant properties into consideration. Do you have a sample landscape document provoking the issue?

Comment: Yes I have one sample landscape document. Why? Do you have a work around for this problem? I tried to rotate the original PDF vertically to put it in portrait, but I got the same problem because the field are now vertical and the text horizontal.

Comment: I ask because there are multiple ways for creating landscape documents in PDF and I wonder whether in your case PDFBox completely ignored an aspect of one such way or merely has a bug in its implementation for that case.

Comment: How can I know how its created?

Comment: If you can provide a sample PDF provoking the issue, other people can inspect.

Comment: I've uploaded it here: http://www.filedropper.com/bx003dgformeude . Thanks for your help. Do you know another library I could use if PDFBox can't do what I want?

Comment: Could it be because this particular form use A4 paper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The short answer*

I'm afraid PDFBox does not yet (as of version 1.8.2) allow you to fill in landscape PDFs like the one you provided because it does not seem to query and factor in informations about the page the form field is located on.

*The long answer*

There are different ways you can define a page to be A4 landscape:

1. You can define it to have the A4 landscape dimensions directly by means of a media box definition:

   ```
   /MediaBox [0, 0, 842, 595]
   ```

   In this case the coordinates of your `aAddressLine1` would be

   ```
   /Rect[23.1711 86.8914 292.121 100.132]
   ```
2. or you can define it to have the A4 portrait dimensions and being rotated by 90° (or 270° obviously):

   ```
   /MediaBox [0, 0, 595, 842]
   /Rotate 90
   ```

   In this case the coordinates of your `aAddressLine1` are

   ```
   /Rect[86.8914 23.1711 100.132 292.121]
   ```

Your example document uses the latter method.

Now PDFBox, when creating an appearance stream for that field, only looks at the rectangle defining the field but ignores the properties of the page. Thus, PDFBox sees a very narrow and very high textfield and fills it in just like that. It is completely unaware that the result will be rotated in a PDF viewer.

[image: Fields filled with PDFBox]

What it should have done is to also look at the page the field is located on. If that page has a **/Rotate** entry, it should create an appearance stream for the field which displays the text rotated in the opposite direction.

*Alternatives*

In a comment you also asked

> Do you know another library I could use if PDFBox can't do what I want?

I have tested the feat with [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) 5.4.2:

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(MY_FILE);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(PATH_HERE);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, os);

    AcroFields acroFields = stamper.getAcroFields();
    acroFields.setField("aAddressLine1", "ADDRESS1_HERE");
    acroFields.setField("aAddressLine2", "ADDRESS1_HERE");
    stamper.close();
```

[image: Fields filled with iText]

(The free iText version is licensed under the AGPL; you have to decide whether that's ok for your project. There is a commercial license, too, if it's not ok.)

I'm sure other PDF libraries also can do that, it's not too exotic a feature after all...

But I also tested [PDF Clown](http://www.stefanochizzolini.it/en/projects/clown/) 0.1.3 (trunk version), which did not work either:

```
File file = new File(MY_FILE);

Document document = file.getDocument();
Form form = document.getForm();
form.getFields().get("aAddressLine1").setValue("ADDRESS1_HERE");
form.getFields().get("aAddressLine2").setValue("ADDRESS1_HERE");

file.save(new java.io.File(PATH_HERE), SerializationModeEnum.Incremental);
file.close();
```

[image: Fields filled with PDF Clown]

Comment: I manage to solve my problem by putting a background image of my form and add form fields on it. Not the cleanest way to do it but it works fine. I'll try iText for my future needs. Thanks for your help.

Comment: hi @mkl,  has there been any update to this with pdfbox 2+?